# How to prompt user of container-bound script to "review permissions"

Tags: google-apps-script

As far as I've read google app script is supposed to show you a prompt to review permissions automatically if you have not authorized your app yet. However this is not happening and I also cannot find a way to manually trigger such a prompt that can be used within `onOpen(e)`.

What I would like to achieve is my app prompting users to review permissions when they have not authorized the app yet.

What I have tried:

- Letting GAS automatically detect used scopes.
- Manually setting scopes using the `appscript.json` file.
- Using `Ui.showModalDialog()` and `ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo().getAuthorizationUrl()` to manually guide the user to permissions. However, this results in the error:

```
Google Apps Script: Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showModalDialog. 
Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are using a simple trigger (`onOpen`). Simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization.

#### Solution:

Install your trigger, either manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, executing this:

```
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("yourOnOpenFunction") // Don't call it onOpen
           .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
           .onOpen()
           .create();
}
```

The authorization is given when installing the trigger.

#### Note:

The installed trigger will run under the account who installed it. Therefore, this is not a good approach if the actions made by the trigger depend on who is executing it, and I'd suggest displaying the dialog through other means, like clicking a button, or similar.

#### Reference:

- [Simple triggers: Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your answer. It definitely answers the question. 

Could you elaborate on your note? If I understand correctly, when I install the trigger on my account all functions and accessed services like DriveApp, etc, etc will also run on my account even if the file is not accessed by me directly, right? Is it possible for the script to run using the accessing user's account instead?

Comment: @Jjampong The only way for this to run under other users would be that they install the onOpen trigger too (also that would cause multiple executions whenever the file is opened, so you should check the executing user email on your function). I don't think it's a good approach though. If you want to access user data on your function, it's much more appropriate that the function is triggered some other way, not via `onOpen`, so that users can authorize the script without having to install a trigger themselves. I hope this solves your doubt.

Comment: Final question, because I may just be misunderstanding something here... The main reason I don't want to install the trigger on my own account is because the app briefly needs access to DriveApp in order to find a few files. This only ever needs to happen once. But seeing as it needs to happen once, authorization needs to be given. I worry that an editor of the container bound to the script dives into the GAS project and uses it to get to my files. Am I needlessly worrying?

Comment: @Jjampong If they execute the function through the script editor, the function will execute under their authorization, which means they'll access their file, not yours. So yeah, no need to worry about this.

Comment: Ah okay. Seems like I misunderstood that part. Thank you very much for your answers :)